# Is there a way to extract all values by some key from a list of maps using SpEL?

Tags: java, spring-el

Let's assume there's a map corresponding to the following structure:

```
{
  "lists": [
    {
      "list": [
        {
          "letter": "a"
        },
        {
          "letter": "b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "list": [
        {
          "letter": "c"
        },
        {
          "letter": "d"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There's an easy way to get all lists using SpEL (`#root['lists']`) or all letters of the first list (`"#root['lists'][0]['list']"`) or the first letter of the first list (`"#root['lists'][0]['list'][0]"`). Also, there's a projection mechanism which allows using construction like `"#root['lists'].![#this['list']]"` to convert each item of `lists` to a result of the projection expression.

However, given all these possibilities, I still failed to come up with an expression allowing me to extract all letters from both lists. For the example above, I'd like to get

```
[
  {
    "letter": "a"
  },
  {
    "letter": "b"
  },
  {
    "letter": "c"
  },
  {
    "letter": "d"
  }
]
```

I tried to use the projection mechanism to achieve my goal but it didn't really help. The problem I see is that every time SpEL detects a list, it applies the projection expression to each element of the list so any structure of nested lists can't be changed this way.

The problem I solve can be easily solved using JsonPath, however, I assume I could get something wrong and didn't notice a way to achieve the same result using SpEL. I would be happy to listen to any ideas.